# My notebook refuses to wake up from sleep after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, wake-up

I had it running Windows 7.
Upgraded to Windows 8 and then to Windows 8.1

The power settings are set to High Performance, which when plugged means:

- Turn off display in 15 mins
- Never sleep
- Closing the lid puts the notebook to sleep

My problem is that it goes to sleep, but then never wakes up. It does not help if I move the mouse or type on the keyboard. The only "rescue" is reboot.

Please, help me troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is it's due to video drivers not being compatible with new Windows update. Try updating your VGA drivers to latest. I found [this blog post](http://www.programmerfish.com/solution-windows-8-1-doesnt-wake-uphangs-after-sleep/) giving five possible solutions. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Oh boy, I am glad you posted it. It was the Virtual Box thing. I uninstalled it and things returned to normal.

Comment: That's Good to know!